# how to enable / disable one radio button if another is selected when id and name are same

Tags: javascript

i have one radio group as

```
<td valign="top" width="37.5%" colspan="3">
```

Actual Days / Month
Only Working Days
Only Working Days + WH
Only Working Days + WH + PH

and another radio group as

```
<td valign="top" width="37.5%" colspan="3">
```

Between Dates
Calender Year
Financial Year
No Leavs Applicable

here i have both id and names same but values different...
my requirement is when i select only working days in group 1, between dates and calender year in group 2 have to be disabled

Comment: Please give some more details ,like what you have tried that will be more helpful. Cases & Examples provided will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedValue= ${radiogroup1:selected}.val();
if(selectedValue=='Only Working Days'){
  ${radiogroup2[value="Between Dates"]}.attr('disable','true');  
  ${radiogroup2[value="Calender Year"]}.attr('disable','true');
}
```

This may be this help.